# Prove the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has infinitely many composite terms $\forall a,b\in\mathbb N$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a sequence s.t. $x_0=1,\;x_{n+1}=ax_n+b$.
Prove the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has infinitely many composite terms $\forall a,b\in\mathbb N$.

I know $x_n=a^n+b(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)$.

I'm trying to find $m$ and $p$ s.t. $$a^m(a+b-1)\equiv b\pmod{p}$$and $\gcd(p,a-1)=1$.

If I do, $p$ divides $x_m$, so $x_{m+(p-1)k}$ is a composite number for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What's your question? (:

Comment: I need proof of that

Comment: Show some attempts.

Comment: @BaSaBu I've edited your question text a bit to make it somewhat more clear. I don't believe I changed your intent anywhere, but please check to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already determined, you have

$$x_n = a^n+b(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \ldots + a + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

First, note that $x_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence, so if a prime $p$ divides more than one element of the sequence, at most the first one of them can be prime (in particular, it would have to be $p$ itself). Next, note if $\gcd(a,b) = d \neq 1$, then $d \mid x_n$ for all $n$, so at most one will be prime (and then only if $d$ itself is prime).

Thus, consider $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. There are now $2$ cases to consider, of $a = 1$ and $a \gt 1$.

**Case $1$: $a = 1$**

Here, \eqref{eq1A} simplifies to

$$x_n = 1 + bn \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

For any prime $p \not\mid b$, note $b$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $p$, so for all $n \equiv -b^{-1}$, you have $p \mid x_n$. As there are an infinite number of such $n$, this means there are an infinite number of composite values of $x_n$, so we're done with this case.

**Case $2$: $a \gt 1$**

Here \eqref{eq1A} can be rewritten as

$$x_n = a^n+b\left(\frac{a^n - 1}{a - 1}\right) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

For all $n \gt 0$, $x_n \gt 1$ so it has prime factors. Consider any prime factor $p \mid x_n$. Since $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, note $p \not\mid a$ because, if it did, then you would get from \eqref{eq1A} that $p \mid b$. Also, since the number of prime factors of $a - 1$ is finite, if the only prime factors among all $x_n$ are among these ones, then there's an infinite number of composite values of $x_n$ and we're done. Otherwise, choose an $n$ so the prime factor $p$ is such that $p \not\mid a - 1$. Next, note you have

$$x_n = a^n + b\left(\frac{a^n - 1}{a - 1}\right) \equiv 0 \pmod p \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

so you can multiply by $a - 1$ to get

$$(a - 1)x_n = a^n(a - 1) + b(a^n - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod p \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), you have that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that

$$a^{n + k(p - 1)} \equiv a^{n}(a^{k(p - 1)}) \equiv a^{n}\left(a^{p-1}\right)^{k} \equiv a^{n} \pmod p \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

You thus have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(a - 1)x_{n + k(p - 1)} & \equiv a^{n + k(p - 1)}(a - 1) + b(a^{n + k(p - 1)} - 1) \pmod p \\
& \equiv (a - 1)x_n = a^n(a - 1) + b(a^n - 1) \pmod p \\
& \equiv 0 \pmod p
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This means $p \mid x_{n + k(p - 1)}$ so, once again, there's an infinite number of composite values among $x_n$. This is shows your idea in the question to end up proving that $x_{x+(p-1)k}$ is composite is valid, but note you should be careful with your notation as you use $x$ for $x_n$ and for an index, i.e., $x + (p - 1)k$.

As this covers all cases and possibilities, you can conclude the proposition you're trying to prove is correct, i.e., the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has infinitely many composite terms $\forall a,b \in \mathbb N$.